# Variadic template data pack strucuture designed for debug/trace log (variable-sized records)

Tags: c++, c++11, template, template-meta-programming

I am currently writing this `pack` template to pack all the values (raw / fundamental + arrays of such, especially c-strings and `std::string`) as a helper for my [`rqueue`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474036/find-untagged-template-options-parameters-args-by-position) - record queue currently used for **debug/trace log** (with remote acces, future plan includes other variable-size records gathered from small devices - PLCs).

### Interface - `template<class... Elements> struct pack`

- `static constexpr size_t count`: Number of stored elements
- `template<size_t I=0> using type`: Type of stored element at index
- `static constexpr bool trivial`: Trivial pack can safely be copied by memcpy
- `T value`: First value (if not empty)
- `pack<Next...> next`: Next values (if any)
- `template<size_t I> type<I>& get()`: Get stored element at index
- `template<size_t I> const type<I>& get() const`: Get stored element at index (const version)
- `size_t length(bool last = true) const`:
  Length is the size in bytes of trivial/flat representation.
  Designed to compute the storage space size to store all contained strings in continuous buffer
  `last`: query length without (true) or with (false) `'\0'` terminator for strings
- `size_t flatten(void *dst, size_t max, bool last = true) const`:
  Flatten will store the data in continous buffer.
  `return`: number of bytes used (compare it with `length()` to see if all the data was successfully stored)
  `dst`: destination buffer pointer
  `max`: size of destination buffer
  `last`: query length without (true) or with (false) `'\0'` terminator for strings
- `template<typename Byte = byte, size_t N> size_t flatten(Byte (&dst)[N], bool last = true) const`: Flatten for fixed-size byte/char array

For [Doxygen](http://doxygen.org) in code:

```
#ifdef FIRDA_DOXYGEN_INVOKED_
namespace firda {

/// Data Pack designed for direct data storage,
/// transfer and variable-sized records.
//:
/// Can embed fundamental types and arrays of fundamental types,
/// especially c-strings (`char[N]`).
/// Supports `std::string` as well, but `trivial` will be `false`
/// and `flatten()` has to be used for continuous storage.

template<class... Elements> struct pack
{

/// Number of stored elements
    static constexpr size_t count;

/// Type of stored element at index
    template<size_t I=0> using type;

/// Trivial pack can safely be copied by memcpy
    static constexpr bool trivial;

/// First value (if not empty)
    T value;
/// Next values (if any)
    pack<Next...> next;

/// Get stored element at index
    template<size_t I> type<I>& get();
/// Get stored element at index (const version)
    template<size_t I> const type<I>& get() const;

/// Length is the size in bytes of trivial/flat representation.
//:
/// Designed to compute the storage space size
/// to store all contained strings in continuous buffer
///\param last query length without (true) or with (false)
/// \c '\0' terminator for strings
    size_t length(bool last = true) const;

/// Flatten will store the data in continous buffer
//:
///\return number of bytes used (compare it with length()
/// to see if all the data was successfully stored)
///\param dst destination buffer pointer
///\param max size of destination buffer
///\param last query length without (true) or with (false)
/// \c '\0' terminator for strings
    size_t flatten(void *dst, size_t max, bool last = true) const;

/// Flatten for fixed-size byte/char array
///\see flatten(void*,size_t,bool)
    template<typename Byte = byte, size_t N>
      size_t flatten(Byte (&dst)[N], bool last = true) const;
};

}
#else
```

Important doxygen config settings:

```
PREDEFINED              = FIRDA_DOXYGEN_INVOKED_
MULTILINE_CPP_IS_BRIEF  = YES
```

### [IdeOne Example](http://ideone.com/5eAu5T)

```
//  c-string vs. c++string
    auto hello = make_pack("hello");
    auto world = make_pack(" world!"_s);
    cout << sizeof(hello) << '/' << hello.length()
      << '+' << sizeof(world) << '/' << world.length()
      << ": " << hello << world << endl;
//  flattening test
    auto again = make_pack("hello again :)"_s);
    char aflat[again.length(false)];
    again.flatten(aflat, sizeof(aflat), false);
    cout << again << endl;
    cout << aflat << endl;
//  complex flattening test
    auto pack = make_pack("pi", ' ', "= "_s, 3.14159f);
    assert(pack.length() == 11);
    char flat[12];
    pack.flatten(flat, false);
    cout << sizeof(pack) << ": " << pack << endl;
    cout << sizeof(flat) << ": " << flat << flat[3] << flat+4
      << pack.get<3>() << " (" << *(float*)(flat+7) << ")" << endl;
    for (auto b : flat) cout << hex << setfill('0') << setw(2) << (word)b;
    cout << dec << endl;
```

Output:

```
6/6+4/7: hello world!
hello again :)
hello again :)
12: pi = 3.14159
12: pi = 3.14159 (3.14159)
706900203d2000ffd00f494008
```

### The Code

```
//######################################################## detail forward
namespace firda { namespace detail_ { namespace pack {

template<class...> struct data;

}}}
//################################################################## pack
namespace firda {

template<class... T> class pack
  : public detail_::pack::data<T...>
{
    typedef detail_::pack::data<T...> base;
public:
    using base::base;
    using base::count;
    using base::trivial;
    using base::length;
    using base::flatten;

    template<typename Byte = byte, size_t N> enable_if_t<
      sizeof(Byte) == 1 && is_integral<Byte>::value,
      size_t> flatten(Byte (&dst)[N], bool last = true) const
    {
        return flatten(dst, N, last);
    }
};

}
#endif
//############################################################# make_pack
namespace firda {

/// Create pack<...> from arguments
template<class... Args> inline
  pack<remove_cref_t<Args>...>
  make_pack(Args&&... args)
{
    return pack<remove_cref_t<Args>...>(
      forward<Args>(args)...);
}

//================================================================ output

/// No output for empty pack
inline ostream& operator << (ostream& s, const pack<>&)
{
    return s;
}

/// Output one packed value
template<class T> inline ostream&
  operator << (ostream& s, const pack<T>& p)
{
    return s << p.value;
}

/// Output more packed values
template<class T, class... N> inline ostream&
  operator << (ostream& s, const pack<T,N...>& p)
{
    return s << p.value << p.next;
}

}
//################################################################ detail
#ifndef FIRDA_DOXYGEN_INVOKED_
namespace firda { namespace detail_ { namespace pack {
#pragma pack(push,1)

// empty data + fallback ------------------------------------------------
template<class... E> struct data
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(E) == 0, "Unmatched argument data");
    static constexpr size_t count = 0;
    static constexpr bool trivial = true;
    size_t length(bool=true)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    size_t flatten(void *dst, size_t max, bool=true)
    {
        return 0;
    }

protected:
    ~data() = default;
};

// trivial element specialization ---------------------------------------
template<class T> struct data<T>
{
    static constexpr size_t count = 1;
    template<size_t I=0> using type = enable_if_t<I==0,T>;
    static constexpr bool trivial = is_trivial<T>::value;
    static_assert(trivial, "Non-trivial element");

    T value;
    data() = default;
    data(const T& value): value(value) {}
    data(T&& value): value(forward<T>(value)) {}

    template<size_t I> type<I>& get()
    {
        static_assert(I == 0, "Index out of range");
        return value;
    }

    template<size_t I> const type<I>& get() const
    {
        static_assert(I == 0, "Index out of range");
        return value;
    }

    size_t length(bool=true) const
    {
        return sizeof(value);
    }

    size_t flatten(void *dst, size_t max, bool=true) const
    {
        size_t sz = sizeof(value);
        if (sz > max) return 0;
        memcpy(dst, &value, sz);
        return sz;
    }

protected:
    ~data() = default;
};

// array specialization -------------------------------------------------
template<class T, size_t N> struct data<T[N]>
{
    static constexpr size_t count = 1;
    template<size_t I=0> using type = enable_if_t<I==0,T[N]>;
    static constexpr bool trivial = is_trivial<T>::value;
    static_assert(trivial, "Non-trivial array");

    T value[N];
    data() = default;
    data(const T value[N])
    {
        copy(value, value+N, this->value);
    }

    template<size_t I> type<I>& get()
    {
        static_assert(I == 0, "Index out of range");
        return value;
    }

    template<size_t I> const type<I>& get() const
    {
        static_assert(I == 0, "Index out of range");
        return value;
    }

    size_t length(bool=true) const
    {
        return sizeof(value);
    }

    size_t flatten(void *dst, size_t max, bool=true) const
    {
        size_t sz = sizeof(value);
        if (sz > max) return 0;
        memcpy(dst, value, sz);
        return sz;
    }

protected:
    ~data() = default;
};

// string specialization ------------------------------------------------
template<> struct data<string>
{
    static constexpr size_t count = 1;
    template<size_t I=0> using type = enable_if_t<I==0,string>;
    static constexpr bool trivial = false;

    string value;
    data() = default;
    data(const string& value): value(value) {}
    data(string&& value): value(forward<string>(value)) {}

    template<size_t I> type<I>& get()
    {
        static_assert(I == 0, "Index out of range");
        return value;
    }

    template<size_t I> const type<I>& get() const
    {
        static_assert(I == 0, "Index out of range");
        return value;
    }

    size_t length(bool last=true) const
    {
        return value.length() + (size_t)!last;
    }

    size_t flatten(void *dst, size_t max, bool last=true) const
    {
        size_t sz = value.length() + (size_t)!last;
        if (sz > max) return 0;
        memcpy(dst, value.c_str(), sz);
        return sz;
    }

protected:
    ~data() = default;
};

// recursive specialization ---------------------------------------------
template<class T, class... Next> struct data<T, Next...> : data<T>
{
    static constexpr size_t count = 1 + sizeof...(Next);
    template<size_t I=0> using type = conditional_t<I==0,
      T, typename data<Next...>::template type<I==0?0:I-1>>;
    static constexpr size_t trivial
      = data<T>::trivial && data<Next...>::trivial;

    using data<T>::value;
    firda::pack<Next...> next;

    data() = default;
    template<class First, class... Args>
      data(First&& value, Args&&... args)
      : data<T>(forward<First>(value))
      , next(forward<Args>(args)...) {}

    using data<T>::get;
    template<size_t I> enable_if_t<I!=0, type<I>&> get()
    {
        static_assert(I < count, "Index out of range");
        return next.template get<I-1>();
    }

    template<size_t I> enable_if_t<I!=0, const type<I>&> get() const
    {
        static_assert(I < count, "Index out of range");
        return next.template get<I-1>();
    }

    size_t length(bool last=true) const
    {
        return data<T>::length(false) + next.length(last);
    }

    size_t flatten(void *dst, size_t max, bool last=true) const
    {
        size_t sz = data<T>::flatten(dst, max, false);
        return sz == 0 ? 0 : next
          .flatten(((byte*)dst) + sz, max - sz, last);
    }

protected:
    ~data() = default;
};

#pragma pack(pop)
}}}
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

### Interface Enhancement

The `get()` is not enough for algorithmization. A way to call some *(templated/universal)* function *(functor)* is needed. For now, this was added:

```
template<class Action>
  bool exec(size_t pos, Action&& action = Action())
    if pos >= count; return false
    if pos == 0; action(value)
    else next.exec(pos-1, forward<Action>(action))
    return true
```

More functions like this are needed (e.g. `for_each`).

### Documentation

The `MULTILINE_CPP_IS_BRIEF = YES` is no longer default behaviour of [**Doxygen**](http://doxygen.org/) and the comments shall therefore be changed:

```
///\brief Data Pack designed for direct data storage,
/// transfer and variable-sized records.
///
/// Can embed fundamental types and arrays of fundamental types,
/// especially c-strings (`char[N]`).
/// Supports `std::string` as well, but `trivial` will be `false`
/// and `flatten()` has to be used for continuous storage.
```

### Tag for SFINAE

The `pack` needs to be identified by a tag (`struct pack_tag`) to allow SFINAE in variadic functions (templated overloading with `enable_if_t`).

```
template<class... Elements> class pack: public pack_tag
```

### Current Code

```
#include "basics.hpp"
namespace firda
///\addtogroup format
///\{
//######################################################## detail forward
#ifndef FIRDA_DOXYGEN_INVOKED_
namespace firda.detail_.pack_
forward template<class...> struct data
namespace firda
#endif
//################################################################### tag

struct pack_tag ///< Tag for data pack (to be used in SFINAE)

//################################################################## doxy
#ifdef FIRDA_DOXYGEN_INVOKED_

///\brief Data Pack designed for direct data storage,
/// transfer and variable-sized records.
///
/// Can embed fundamental types and arrays of fundamental types,
/// especially c-strings (`char[N]`).
/// Supports `std::string` as well, but `trivial` will be `false`
/// and `flatten()` has to be used for continuous storage.

///\ingroup rqueue
template<class... Elements> class pack: public pack_tag
public:
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
/// Number of stored elements
    static constexpr size_t count = sizeof...(Elements)

/// Type of stored element at index
    template<size_t I=0> using type = ...

/// Trivial pack can safely be copied by memcpy
    static constexpr bool trivial = ...

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
/// First value (if not empty)
    T value
/// Next values (if any)
    pack<Next...> next

/// Default construct the pack
    pack() = default
/// Pass each argument to apropriate `value` constructor
    template<class... Args> pack(Args&&... args)

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
/// Get stored element at index
    template<size_t I> type<I>& get()
/// Get stored element at index (const version)
    template<size_t I> const type<I>& get() const

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
///\brief Length is the size in bytes of trivial/flat representation.
///
/// Designed to compute the storage space size
/// to store all contained strings in continuous buffer.
///\param last query length without (true) or with (false)
/// \c '\0' terminator for strings
    size_t length(bool last = true) const

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
///\brief Flatten will store the data in continous buffer
///\return number of bytes used (compare it with length()
/// to see if all the data was successfully stored)
    size_t flatten
      ( void *dst   ///< destination buffer pointer
      , size_t max  ///< max size of destination buffer
      , bool last   ///\param last query length without (true)
      = true) const /// or with (false) \c '\0' terminator for strings

/// Flatten for fixed-size byte/char array
///\see flatten(void*,size_t,bool) const
    template<typename Byte = byte, size_t N>
      size_t flatten(Byte (&dst)[N], bool last = true) const

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
/// Execute action with element at position
///\return false if `pos` out of range
    template<class Action> bool
      exec
      ( size_t pos      ///< position (index) of the element
      , Action&& action ///< action (functor) to execute on the element
      = Action() )
/// Execute action with element at position (const version)
///\return false if `pos` out of range
    template<class Action> bool
      exec
      ( size_t pos      ///< position (index) of the element
      , Action&& action ///< action (functor) to execute on the element
      = Action() ) const

#else
//################################################################## pack

template<class... T> class pack
  : public pack_tag
  , public detail_::pack_::data<T...>
    typedef detail_::pack_::data<T...> base
public:
    using base: base, count, trivial, length, flatten

    template<typename Byte = byte, size_t N> enable_if_t<
      sizeof(Byte) == 1 && is_integral<Byte>::value,
      size_t> flatten(Byte (&dst)[N], bool last = true) const
        return flatten(dst, N, last)

#endif

/// Get pack type at index (const, volatile and reference removed)
template<size_t I, class... Elements> using pack_t
  = typename pack<remove_cvref_t<Elements>...>::template type<I>

//############################################################# make_pack

/// Create pack<...> from arguments (const, volatile and reference removed)
template<class... Args> inline
  pack<remove_cvref_t<Args>...>
  make_pack(Args&&... args)
    return pack<remove_cvref_t<Args>...>(
      forward<Args>(args)...)

//================================================================ output

#ifdef FIRDA_DOXYGEN_INVOKED_

/// Output packed values
template<class... Elements> inline ostream&
  operator << (ostream& s, const pack<Elements...>& p)

#else

/// No output for empty pack
inline ostream& operator << (ostream& s, const pack<>&)
    return s

/// Output one packed value
template<class T> inline ostream&
  operator << (ostream& s, const pack<T>& p)
    return s << p.value

/// Output more packed values
template<class T, class... N> inline ostream&
  operator << (ostream& s, const pack<T,N...>& p)
    return s << p.value << p.next

#endif

//################################################################ detail
#ifndef FIRDA_DOXYGEN_INVOKED_
namespace firda.detail_.pack_
#pragma pack(push,1)

// empty data + fallback ------------------------------------------------
template<class... E> struct data
    static_assert(sizeof...(E) == 0, "Unmatched arguments")
    static constexpr size_t count = 0
    static constexpr bool trivial = true

    size_t length(bool=true)
        return 0
    size_t flatten(void *dst, size_t max, bool=true)
        return 0

    template<class Action>
      bool exec(size_t pos, Action&& action = Action())
        return false
    template<class Action>
      bool exec(size_t pos, Action&& action = Action()) const
        return false

protected:
    ~data() = default

// trivial element specialization ---------------------------------------
template<class T> struct data<T>
    static constexpr size_t count = 1
    template<size_t I=0> using type = enable_if_t<I==0,T>
    static constexpr bool trivial = is_trivial<T>::value
    static_assert(trivial, "Non-trivial element")

    T value
    data() = default
    data(const T& value): value(value) {}
    data(T&& value): value(forward<T>(value)) {}

    template<size_t I> type<I>& get()
        static_assert(I == 0, "Index out of range")
        return value
    template<size_t I> const type<I>& get() const
        static_assert(I == 0, "Index out of range")
        return value

    size_t length(bool=true) const
        return sizeof(value)
    size_t flatten(void *dst, size_t max, bool=true) const
        size_t sz = sizeof(value)
        if sz > max; return 0
        memcpy(dst, &value, sz)
        return sz

    template<class Action>
      bool exec(size_t pos, Action&& action = Action())
        if pos > 0; return false
        action(value)
        return true
    template<class Action>
      bool exec(size_t pos, Action&& action = Action()) const
        if pos > 0; return false
        action(value)
        return true

protected:
    ~data() = default

// array specialization -------------------------------------------------
template<class T, size_t N> struct data<T[N]>
    static constexpr size_t count = 1
    template<size_t I=0> using type = enable_if_t<I==0,T[N]>
    static constexpr bool trivial = is_trivial<T>::value
    static_assert(trivial, "Non-trivial array")

    T value[N]
    data() = default
    data(const T value[N])
        copy(value, value+N, this->value)

    template<size_t I> type<I>& get()
        static_assert(I == 0, "Index out of range")
        return value
    template<size_t I> const type<I>& get() const
        static_assert(I == 0, "Index out of range")
        return value

    size_t length(bool=true) const
        return sizeof(value)
    size_t flatten(void *dst, size_t max, bool=true) const
        size_t sz = sizeof(value)
        if sz > max; return 0
        memcpy(dst, value, sz)
        return sz

    template<class Action>
      bool exec(size_t pos, Action&& action = Action())
        if pos > 0; return false
        action(value)
        return true
    template<class Action>
      bool exec(size_t pos, Action&& action = Action()) const
        if pos > 0; return false
        action(value)
        return true

protected:
    ~data() = default

// string specialization ------------------------------------------------
template<> struct data<string>
    static constexpr size_t count = 1
    template<size_t I=0> using type = enable_if_t<I==0,string>
    static constexpr bool trivial = false

    string value
    data() = default
    data(const string& value): value(value) {}
    data(string&& value): value(forward<string>(value)) {}

    template<size_t I> type<I>& get()
        static_assert(I == 0, "Index out of range")
        return value
    template<size_t I> const type<I>& get() const
        static_assert(I == 0, "Index out of range")
        return value

    size_t length(bool last=true) const
        return value.length() + (size_t)!last
    size_t flatten(void *dst, size_t max, bool last=true) const
        size_t sz = value.length() + (size_t)!last
        if sz > max; return 0
        memcpy(dst, value.c_str(), sz)
        return sz

    template<class Action>
      bool exec(size_t pos, Action&& action = Action())
        if pos > 0; return false
        action(value)
        return true
    template<class Action>
      bool exec(size_t pos, Action&& action = Action()) const
        if pos > 0; return false
        action(value)
        return true

protected:
    ~data() = default

// recursive specialization ---------------------------------------------
template<class T, class... Next> struct data<T, Next...> : data<T>
    static constexpr size_t count = 1 + sizeof...(Next)
    template<size_t I=0> using type = conditional_t<I==0,
      T, typename data<Next...>::template type<I==0?0:I-1>>
    static constexpr size_t trivial
      = data<T>::trivial && data<Next...>::trivial

    using data<T>::value
    firda::pack<Next...> next

    data() = default
    template<class First, class... Args>
      data(First&& value, Args&&... args)
      : data<T>(forward<First>(value))
      , next(forward<Args>(args)...) {}

    using data<T>::get
    template<size_t I> enable_if_t<I!=0, type<I>&> get()
        static_assert(I < count, "Index out of range")
        return next.template get<I-1>()
    template<size_t I> enable_if_t<I!=0, const type<I>&> get() const
        static_assert(I < count, "Index out of range")
        return next.template get<I-1>()

    size_t length(bool last=true) const
        return data<T>::length(false) + next.length(last)
    size_t flatten(void *dst, size_t max, bool last=true) const
        size_t sz = data<T>::flatten(dst, max, false)
        return sz == 0 ? 0 : next
          .flatten(((byte*)dst) + sz, max - sz, last)

    template<class Action>
      bool exec(size_t pos, Action&& action = Action())
        if pos >= count; return false
        if pos == 0; action(value)
        else next.exec(pos-1, forward<Action>(action))
        return true
    template<class Action>
      bool exec(size_t pos, Action&& action = Action()) const
        if pos >= count; return false
        if pos == 0; action(value)
        else next.exec(pos-1, forward<Action>(action))
        return true

protected:
    ~data() = default

#pragma pack(pop)
//#######################################################################
namespace firda
#endif // doxy
///\}
```