# printf-like formatting for std::ostream ~ (not exactly) boost::format

Tags: c++, strings, c++11, stream

```
cout << format(
  "%? %?!\n"            // Hello world!
  "%1% %3% :)\n"        // Hello again :)
  "%%05X: %05X\n"       // %05X: 01234
  "%%g: %g\n"           // %g: 3.14159
  "%%.3f: %5$.3f\n"  // %.3f: 3.142
  , "Hello", "world", "again"
  , 0x1234, 3.14159265f);
```

1. The above shows the usage of universal formatting - `%?` which wil just take the argument and pass it to `ostream << it` (`"Hello"` and `"world!"`).
2. Next line shows **positional** specifier - `%1% %3%` (alternatively `%1$? %3$s`) to explicitly select *first and third* arguments (`"Hello"` and `"again"`).
3. `%%` outputs single `%`, `0` changes to zero-padding, `5` sets the **width** and `X` will do:
   `out << hex << uppercase << it`.
4. `%g` is `out << defaultfloat << it` and probably still needs some work.
5. `%5$.3f` uses positional and **precision** specifiers.

---

### How it works

The `format` is variadic function that will create `format_pack` which is derived from my [`data pack`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/62765/variadic-template-data-pack-strucuture-designed-for-debug-trace-log-variable-si):

```
/// Tag for data pack with format string
struct format_pack_tag {};

/// Data pack with format string
template<class String = string, class... Elements>
  class format_pack
  : public format_pack_tag
  , public pack<String, Elements...> {
public:
    template<class... Args>
      format_pack(Args&&... args)
      : pack<String, Elements...>
      ( forward<Args>(args)...) {}
};

/// Create data pack with format string
template<class String, class... Elements>
  inline format_pack<remove_cvref_t<String>,
  remove_cvref_t<Elements>...>
  format(String&& fmt, Elements&&... e) {
    return format_pack<remove_cvref_t<String>,
      remove_cvref_t<Elements>...>(
      forward<String>(fmt),
      forward<Elements>(e)...);
}

//=======================================================================

/// Stream-out the string
template<class String>
  inline ostream& operator << (ostream& out,
  const format_pack<String>& it) {
    return out << it.value;
}

/// Stream-out the formatted data
template<class String, class... Elements>
  inline ostream& operator << (ostream& out,
  const format_pack<String, Elements...>& it) {
    formatting::formatter(out, c_str(it.value), it.next);
    return out;
}
```

There are some helpers used:

- `remove_cvref_t` = `remove_cv_t<remove_reference_t<T>>` (C++14 style)
- `c_str` will either return its `const char *` argument or call `c_str()` on `std::string`.

### The Formatter

```
/// Formatting engine (short-lived, designed to do the job and dismiss)
struct formatter {
    const char *fmt;
    ostream& out;
    state sta;

///\copydoc formatting::advance()
    const char * advance() {
        return fmt = formatting::advance(fmt, out);
    }

///\copydoc formatting::prepare()
    const char * prepare() {
        const char * pos = formatting::prepare(fmt, out, sta);
        if (!pos) {
            out.clear();
            out << (fmt-1);
            out.setstate(ios::failbit);
        }
        return fmt = pos;
    }

///\copydoc formatting::output()
    template<class T>
      const char * output(const T& data) {
        const char * pos = formatting::output(fmt, out, data, sta.flags);
        if (!pos) {
            out.clear();
            out << fmt;
            out.setstate(ios::failbit);
        }
        return fmt = pos;
    }

///\copydoc output()
    template<class T>
      void operator() (const T& data) {
        output(data);
    }

/// Stream-out the format string (no data)
    formatter(ostream& out, const char * fmt)
      : out(out), fmt(nullptr) {
        out << fmt;
    }
/// Stream-out formatted data
    template<class... Elements>
      formatter(ostream& out, const char * fmt
      , const pack<Elements...>& data)
      : out(out), fmt(fmt) {
        sta.apos = 0;
        for(;;) {
            if (!advance()) return;
            if (!prepare()) return;
            if (!data.exec(sta.apos, *this)) break;
            ++sta.apos;
        }
        out.setstate(ios::failbit);
        out << fmt;
        fmt = nullptr;
    }
};
```

### The Formatting (the hidden logic)

- `advance()` will find the `%` (skipping any `%%`)
- `prepare()` will parse **positional, width and precision** specifiers
- `output()` will output the value and is overloaded with some SFINAE
  (arithmetic, pointers, strings and all other).

```
namespace formatting {

///\brief Advance to next format specifier (\c '%')
///\return position of '%' or nullptr
inline const char* advance
  ( const char* pos     ///< position in format string
  , ostream& out        ///< output stream
  ) {
    const char* at = pos;
    for(;;) {
        if (*at != '%') do {
            if (!*at) {
                out.write(pos, at-pos);
                return nullptr;
            }
        } while (*++at != '%');
        if (*++at != '%') break;
        out.write(pos, at-pos);
        pos = ++at;
    }
    out.write(pos, at-1-pos);
    return at;
}

/// Formatter state
struct state {
public:
    uint apos;      ///< argument position
    uint flags;     ///< additional flags
    enum {
        space   = 1<< 0,    ///< ' ' specifier (sign)
        center  = 1<< 1 ///< '=' specifier (alignment)
    };
};

//TODO: use flags in output()

//=======================================================================
///\brief Prepare output stream state
///\return position of conversion specifier (after \c %w.p)
/// or `nullptr` on error + failbit on `out` (can throw).
inline const char *prepare
  ( const char* spec        ///< position in format string after \c '%'
  , ostream& out            ///< output stream
  , state& sta              ///< formatter state
  ) {
    out.flags(ios::right|ios::dec);
    out.fill(' ');
    out.width(0);
    out.precision(6);
    sta.flags = 0;
    for(;;) {
        char c = *spec++;
        switch (c) {
    //  unknown character -> pass to output()
        default:
            return --spec;
    //  these are ignored (argument types for printf)
        case 'h': case 'l': case 'j': case 'z': case 't': case 'L':
            continue;
    //  adjustfield
        case '-':
            out.setf(ios::left, ios::adjustfield);
            continue;
        case '=':
            sta.flags |= state::center;
            continue;
    //  fill
        case '0':
            out.fill('0');
            continue;
    //  sign
        case '+':
            out.setf(ios::showpos);
            continue;
        case ' ':
            sta.flags |= state::space;
            continue;
    //  width or position
        case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
        case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8':
        case '9':
            { const char* num = spec-1;
                while (isdigit(*spec)) ++spec;
                int w = atoi(num);
                if (*spec == '%' || *spec == '$') {
                    sta.apos = (uint)(w-1);
                    if (*spec == '%') {
                        return spec;
                    }
                    ++spec;
                    continue;
                }
                out.width(w);
            }
            continue;
    //  precision
        case '.':
        //TODO: use some flag for this check
        //  if out.precision() != 6
        //  //  second precision specifier
        //      out.setstate(ios::failbit)
        //      return nullptr
            { const char* num = spec;
                while (isdigit(*spec)) ++spec;
                out.precision(atoi(num));
            }
            continue;
        }
    }
}

//################################################################ output
#ifdef FIRDA_DOXYGEN_INVOKED_

///\brief Format the value.
///\return position after format specification
/// or `nullptr` on error + failbit on `out` (can throw).
template<class T> const char* output
  ( const char* spec    ///< position in format string after '%'
  , ostream& out        ///< output stream
  , const T& it         ///< value to be formatted
  , uint flags = 0      ///< formatter flags
  );

#else

/// Format arithmetic value
template<class T> inline
  enable_if_t<is_arithmetic<T>::value,
  const char*>
  output
  ( const char* spec    ///< position in format string after '%'
  , ostream& out        ///< output stream
  , T it                ///< value to be formatted
  , uint flags = 0      ///< formatter flags
  ) {
    char c = *spec++;
    if (isupper(c)) {
        c = tolower(c);
        out.setf(ios::uppercase);
    }
    switch (c) {
    default:
        out.setstate(ios::failbit);
        return nullptr;
    case '?': case '%':
        out << it;
        break;
    case 'd': case 'i':
        out << dec << try_make_signed_t<T>(it);
        break;
    case 'u':
        out << dec << try_make_unsigned_t<T>(it);
        break;
    case 'x':
        out << hex << it;
        break;
    case 'o':
        out << oct << it;
        break;
    case 'g':
        out << defaultfloat << it;
        break;
    case 'f':
        out << fixed << it;
        break;
    case 'e':
        out << scientific << it;
        break;
//FIXME: consider signed vs. unsigned
    case 'c': case 's':
        out << char(it);
        break;
    }
//TODO: case '#' - special formatting
    return spec;
}

//=======================================================================
/// Format pointer
template<class T> inline
  enable_if_t<!is_same<T,char>::value,
  const char*>
  output
  ( const char* spec    ///< position in format string after '%'
  , ostream& out        ///< output stream
  , const T* it         ///< value to be formatted
  , uint flags = 0      ///< formatter flags
  ) {
    char c = *spec++;
    if (isupper(c)) {
        c = tolower(c);
        out.setf(ios::uppercase);
    }
    switch (c) {
    case 'p':
        out << hex << uintptr_t(it);
        return spec;
    default:
        if (!it) {
        //TODO: skip custom format
            out << "null";
            return spec;
        }
        return output(spec, out, *it);
    }
}

//=======================================================================
/// Format string
template<class String> inline
  enable_if_t<is_same<String,const char *>::value
  || is_same<String,const string&>::value,
  const char*>
  output
  ( const char* spec    ///< position in format string after '%'
  , ostream& out        ///< output stream
  , String it           ///< string to be formatted
  , uint flags = 0      ///< formatter flags
  ) {
    out << it;
    return ++spec;
}

//=======================================================================
/// Format generic
template<class T> inline
  enable_if_t<!is_fundamental<decay_t<T>>::value
  && !is_pointer<decay_t<T>>::value,
  const char*>
  output
  ( const char* spec    ///< position in format string after '%'
  , ostream& out        ///< output stream
  , const T& it         ///< value to be formatted
  , uint flags = 0      ///< formatter flags
  ) {
    char c = *spec++;
    if (isupper(c)) {
        c = tolower(c);
        out.setf(ios::uppercase);
    }
    switch (c) {
//TODO: some conversions for cdiuxgfe (char, long long, long double)
    default:
        out.setstate(ios::failbit);
        return nullptr;
    case 's': case '?': case '%':
        out << it;
        break;
    }
    return spec;
}

#endif
```

### Finally - delegated formatting

All I wanted was to create some engine for remote debug/trace log, to store all the data (with some code/ID) in some queue without actually formatting it and let another (debug) thread do the formatting (and output to `cout` or `syslog`). Just an example how it can be done:

```
struct record_base
    virtual ostream& print(ostream&) = 0
    virtual ~record_base() {}

template<class Pack>
  struct record_impl
  : record_base
    Pack pack
    template<class... Args>
      record_impl(Args&&... args)
      : pack(forward<Args>(args)...) {}
    ostream& print(ostream& out) override
        return out << pack

template<class String, class... Args>
  unique_ptr<record_base>
  record(String&& fmt, Args&&... args)
    return unique_ptr<record_base>(new record_impl<
      format_pack<string, remove_cref_t<Args>...> >
      ( forward<String>(fmt), forward<Args>(args)...) )

int main()
    record(
      "%? %?!\n"            // Hello world!
      "%1% %3% :)\n"        // Hello again :)
      "%%05X: %05X\n"       // %05X: 01234
      "%%g: %g\n"           // %g: 3.14159
      "%%.3f: %5$.3f\n"     // %.3f: 3.142
      , "Hello", "world", "again"
      , 0x1234, 3.14159265f
      ).get()->print(cout)
```

Comment: Why not use printf (or even sprintf), instead of that monstrosity?

Comment: @BЈовић: 1. Position specifier is not standardized (but really good for localization). 2. The format string does not need to specify the exact type. 3. Objects are no longer problem. 4. It is quite extensible (e.g. '=' for centered output - not finished, but already in `prepare()`. Knows what `ostream` knows). 5. It does not use temporary string, the output is direct. 6. I already had that data pack class and rqueue (because of PLCs), it was just natural to write this `format()`.

Comment: Looks like `advance` doesn't parse embedded strings diligently: in `"\"%\""` it will pick up a percent sign as a formatting one.

Comment: @vnp: Will that be different with `printf`? I don't think so, you have to write double: `"\"%%\""`, it is not designed to understand whatever logic, you may wish to format something within the string: `"\"%s\""`

Comment: @BЈовић: Because `sprintf()` is not type safe. You should never use it in C++ code. This code should be type safe (not read the details). But `monstrosity` is a very loaded word. If you look at `std::vector<>` under the covers its a `monstrosity` but the interface it provides to the user should make using it clean and reduce errors.

Comment: @firda: Why not just use boost::format? http://stackoverflow.com/a/119194/14065 which also provides positional parameter formatting http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/format/doc/format.html a requirement for doing any localization.

Comment: @LokiAstari: Boost::format is of course valid, it could be used. I have avoided boost so far, this version does not use temporary string (boost format do), the formatting is done in function call (unlike boost - `operator %`). ...but it can be marked *reinventing the wheel* if you wish.

Comment: @firda, people have asked "why not printf/boost.format", but why not `std::ostream` - like interface? Formatted strings output interface over `std::ostream`, is still more error prone than using `std::ostream` directly (or an `std::ostream`-like interface/wrapper over `std::ostream`). So, why do you want printf-like interface?

Comment: @utnapistim: Imagine trace function or macro, used like `TRACE(dbgcode::something, "User %s, ip %?, command %02x, error %d", user->name, ip, cmd, err)` and some system of remote log access. What I want is to place all the data (except format string) to some buffer/queue I can remotedly access + format some of the traces to syslog. The trace should first place everythig (unformatted) in one synchronized queue. Another thread will pop it, format and place in specific queue (according to code) which can then be remotedly accessed and examined.

Comment: @utnapistim: Why not `ostream` directly? Well, I want to delegate the formatting to another thread, not to slow the one which I want to trace. There is a chance I will mess the error codes, format strings and arguments, but that would result in `failbit` on the stream and the rest of the format string printed out. The `failbit` can then be detected, logged and no other trace will be touched by it.

Comment: @firda, I implemented something similar about 6-7 years ago. The arguments were enqueued on the client thread (copy construction for each) and passed to a background logging thread. Even so, it would be much better to encode a `Message` class (that goes on the queue) and add an `operator<<(Message&, T const& your_data)` template than all this _plus_ format string construction, processing and validation. There is also one "gotcha" with this architecture: the application may crash and if it does, you don't see the log (because the messages are still enqueued in memory, and lost on coredump).

Comment: @utnapistim: If it crashes then not even syslog will save me (so many threads, no clue which one was the bad). I rather write automatic tests which I run before deploying. This is more of trace log, which I want to use to see what was happening. Which client terminated too early, how many bad logins, what bad command was involved, what IP address, which device ID etc. ....class for each trace record? Ahh, 100 classes... this solution is more *productive* and can be used for ad-hoc debug traces as well.

Answer (score 1):

### Pointers and order of `formatting::output` overloads

The output for pointers should be last or forwarding has to be used, but there is a problem with pointers to unformattable objects - it won't compile even when we use simple `%p` formatting. **Dropped** (no more redirection, pointers shall be formatted as integral types, where `%p` is same as `%x`).

### The very packing of arguments

Using that `data pack` together with `remove_cvref_t` seems not to be the best choice. It would be better to use similar structure without that `#pragma pack(1)` and following type selection:

```
/// Type selection for format pack
template<typename T> struct format_element_type
private:
    using X = remove_reference_t<T>
    static constexpr bool simple
      = is_pointer<X>::value
      || (is_fundamental<X>::value
      && sizeof(X) <= sizeof(void*))
public:
    using type = conditional_t<simple, X, X&>

template<typename T> using format_t
  = typename format_element_type<T>::type

/// Create data pack with format string
template<class String, class... Elements>
  inline format_pack<format_t<String>
  , format_t<Elements>...>
  format(String&& fmt, Elements&&... e)
    return format_pack<format_t<String>
      , format_t<Elements>...>
      ( forward<String>(fmt)
      , forward<Elements>(e)...)
```

### Benchmarking and possible format literals

As already suggested, packed references (like with [`tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) creating [`tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) of references) are better then copying the whole object (and it is sometimes even not possible), but some fundamental types and pointers could be passed directly (but beware of arrays - `decay_t` is no good either, we have to preserve the information about number of elements). It should produce type-safe alternative to [`va_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_list) (which is the reason for that `sizeof(X) <= sizeof(void*)` - fast indexing / positional specifier handling is to be examined and benchmarked).

Some compile-time parsing of format string (e.g. `operator "" _fmt(const char *str, size_t len)`) could help with selecting faster implementation (especially if the string contains no positional specifiers). Put all together, we could produce type-safe alternative to `snprintf` this way, that could possibly be even faster (because of compile-time type resolution and implementation selection).

As this is getting too much *conceptual* for CR, I will consider moving to [programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/126340/alternate-string-formatting-options-in-c).

### Comparision to `boost::format`

There still seems to be some advantages over `boost::format` in the fact that all the arguments are available immediatelly by the method selected - function call. Other than that, boost::format can be adapted to produce almost the same results (there is no `%?` universal formatting, positional `%1%` has to be used with boost AFAIK).

**Simple experiments:**
(`frefs` refers to `format` creation included in the code bellow, which uses the `tuple-tie` approach)

```
template<class String, class... Elements>
  inline firda::format_pack<String, Elements...>
  format(String&& fmt, Elements&&... e)
    return firda::format_pack<String, Elements...>(
      std::forward<String>(fmt), std::forward<Elements>(e)...)

template<class... Args> void apply(boost::format& bf, Args&&... args)
    return
template<class T, class... Args> void apply
  ( boost::format& bf, T&& arg, Args&&... args )
    bf % arg
    apply(bf, args...)

template<class... Args> void test(const char * fmt, Args&&... args)
    std::cout << "firda: " << firda::format(fmt, args...) << std::endl
    std::cout << "frefs: " << format(fmt, args...) << std::endl

    boost::format bf(fmt)
    apply(bf, args...)
    std::cout << "boost: " << bf << std::endl

struct simple
    std::string text
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const simple& it)
        return out << it.text

int main()
    test("hello %s!", "world")
    test("pi = %g", 3.14159265)
    test("simple: %1%", simple{"text"})
```

### The Syntax

Python/Ruby programmers should find my altered syntax a bit familiar, although it is not and never will be Python/Ruby, it is still C++ with altered syntax, nothing more, nothing less.

---

### Some more code for utnapistim (the remote trace log)

*(The `rqueue` does not need to allocate individual records. It rather asks through `record_size` and `record_type` how much space is needed and what type is to be used for construction of the record. There is no allocation and/or moving at all with `fixed_size<>` option - everything is embedded within the buffer.)*

```
///\brief Remote Trace Log \file
#include "rqueue.hpp" "thread.hpp" "format.hpp"
namespace firda
///\addtogroup rqueue
///\{

/// Trace record designed to pack all data for delayed formatting
class trace_record
    template<class...> friend class rqueue

/// Enables polymorphic destruction (for rqueue only)
    virtual ~trace_record() {}

public:
/// 1.1.2000 0:00
    static constexpr time_point<system_clock> epoch
      = time_point<system_clock>(seconds(946681200))

    const uint time     ///< seconds since 1.1.2000 0:00
    const byte centi    ///< 1/100 second fraction
    const byte size     ///< size of record payload in bytes
    const word code     ///< record type identificator

/// Print payload to `ostream` (record header not formatted)
    virtual ostream& output(ostream& out) const
        return out
/// Compute size of payload flat representation
    virtual size_t length() const
        return 0
/// Flatten payload to buffer
    virtual size_t flatten(void* dst, size_t max) const
        return 0

/// Flat version of the record (can be constructed from `trace_record`)
    class flat
        template<class...> friend class rqueue

    public:
        const uint time     ///< seconds since 1.1.2000 0:00
        const byte centi    ///< 1/100 second fraction
        const byte size     ///< size of record payload in bytes
        const word code     ///< record type identificator
        const void *data() const
            return (const void *)(this + 1)
        const byte *bytes() const
            return (const byte *)data()
        const byte& operator[] (size_t i) const
            return *(bytes() + i)

    private:
        flat(size_t sz, const trace_record& src)
          : time(src.time), centi(src.centi)
          , size(sz - sizeof(flat)), code(src.code)
            assert(size == src.length())
            src.flatten((void*)(this+1), size)
        static size_t record_size(const trace_record& src)
            return sizeof(flat) + src.length()
        size_t record_size() const
            return sizeof(flat) + size
        void record_move(void *dst)
            memcpy(dst, this, record_size())
        template<class...> using
          record_type = flat

private:
#ifndef FIRDA_DOXYGEN_INVOKED_
    forward template<class... Elements>
      class data
    template<class... Args>
      struct record_type_
    template<class Code>
      struct record_type_<Code>
        typedef trace_record type
    template<class Code, class Format, class... Args>
      struct record_type_<Code, Format, Args...>
        typedef data<remove_cvref_t<Args>...> type
#endif

    template<class...> friend class data
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, const trace_record&)

    trace_record(uint64_t ms, byte size, word code)
      : time(ms / 1000), centi(ms / 10 % 100)
      , size(size), code(code) {}
    trace_record(byte size, word code)
      : trace_record(duration_cast<milliseconds>
      ( system_clock::now() - epoch ).count()
      , size, code) {}

    size_t record_size() const
        return sizeof(trace_record) + size
    virtual void record_move(void *dst)
        new(dst) trace_record(move(*this))

    template<class... Args> using fpack
      = format_pack<const char *, remove_cvref_t<Args>...>
    template<class... Args> using
      record_type = typename record_type_<Args...>::type

    template<class... Args> static size_t
      record_size(word, const char *, Args&&...)
        return sizeof(record_type<word, const char *, Args...>)

//=======================================================================
/// Trace record implementation (for rqueue only)
template<class... Elements>
  class trace_record::data
  : trace_record, fpack<Elements...>
    typedef fpack<Elements...> fpack
    template<class...> friend class firda::rqueue
    template<class... Args>
      data(size_t sz, word code, const char *fmt, Args&&... args)
      : trace_record((byte)(sz-sizeof(trace_record)), code)
      , fpack(fmt, forward<Args>(args)...)
        assert(size == sizeof(data)-sizeof(trace_record))
    virtual void record_move(void *dst) override
        new(dst) data(move(*this))
public:
    virtual ostream& output(ostream& out) const override
        return out << (const fpack&)*this

//=======================================================================
#ifndef FIRDA_DOXYGEN_INVOKED_
template<class First, class... Next>
  class trace_record::data<First, Next...>
  : trace_record, fpack<First, Next...>
    typedef fpack<First, Next...> fpack
    template<class...> friend class firda::rqueue
    template<class... Args>
      data(size_t sz, word code, const char *fmt, Args&&... args)
      : trace_record((byte)(sz-sizeof(trace_record)), code)
      , fpack(fmt, forward<Args>(args)...)
        assert(size == sizeof(data)-sizeof(trace_record))
    virtual void record_move(void *dst) override
        new(dst) data(move(*this))
public:
    virtual ostream& output(ostream& out) const override
        return out << (const fpack&)*this
    virtual size_t length() const
        return fpack::next.length()
    virtual size_t flatten(void* dst, size_t max) const
        return fpack::next.flatten(dst, max)
#endif
//=======================================================================

inline ostream& operator << (ostream& out,
  const trace_record& rec)
    if !rec.size; return out << format("%04x", rec.code)
    out << format("%04x: ", rec.code)
    return rec.output(out)

inline ostream& operator << (ostream& out,
  const trace_record::flat& rec)
    out.setf(ios::right|ios::hex, ios::adjustfield|ios::basefield)
    out.fill('0'); out << setw(2) << (uint)rec.size
    for uint i = 0; i < rec.size; ++i
        out << setw(2) << (uint)rec[i]
    return out

///\}
```