# Templated string formatting

Tags: c++, strings, formatting, template, variadic

This function formats a string by replacing every occurrence of '{n}' with the corresponding argument that was passed to the function where `n` is an index that starts at 0. The same index can be used multiple times and the order is irrelevant. If `n` is out of bounds or cannot be converted to an integer number I just add '{n}' to the result. The function is intended to be used e.g with config files that can be changed by the user where it would be unsafe to use `sprintf`. The use of `std::ostringstream` allows me to pass any type that has an overloaded `<<` operator. I was considering using iterators in the loops but I'm not sure whether that would gain anything.

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <string_view>

namespace util::str{
    inline void to_string_vector(std::vector<std::string>&){} //Dummy used to end recursion

    template<typename T, typename ... Args>
    void to_string_vector(std::vector<std::string>& result, const T& t, Args&& ...args){
        result.push_back((std::ostringstream{} << t).str());
        to_string_vector(result, args...);
    }

    template<typename ... Args>
    std::string format(std::string_view fmt, Args&& ...args){
        std::string result;
        std::vector<std::string> values;

        result.reserve(fmt.size());
        to_string_vector(values, args...);

        for(std::size_t first = 0; first < fmt.size(); ++first){
            if(fmt[first] == '{'){
                for(std::size_t second = first + 1; second < fmt.size(); ++second){
                    if(fmt[second] == '}'){
                        try{
                            std::size_t index = std::stoi(std::string{fmt.substr(first + 1, second - first - 1)});

                            if(index < values.size())
                                result += values[index];
                            else
                                result += fmt.substr(first, second - first + 1);
                        }catch(...){
                            result += fmt.substr(first, second - first + 1);
                        }

                        first = second;

                        break;
                    }else if(fmt[second] == '{'){
                        result += fmt.substr(first, second - first);
                        first = second - 1;

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }else{
                result.push_back(fmt[first]);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code could use some *prettification* (whitespaces) and you could possibly avoid creating the vector of strings by working directly with `ostream`, but it works and looks ok. Any concerns and/or future plans?

Comment: @firda Thanks for the feedback. I’m not a big fan of too many whitespaces. I find them more annoying than helpful. Where would you suggest I add some more? I’m using the vector so that I can directly use the parsed index to look up the value. Not sure how I could do this directly with ostream.

Comment: At least after `}` and before `{` when there is something else after/before: `} else {` and `if(fmt[second] == '}') {`, maybe after keywords (`if (...` and `for (`) but that would be bonus :)

Comment: As for the vector, well, such solution could be too advanced for you (e.g. capturing the arguments in a tuple). You can take a look at [my own](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63578/printf-like-formatting-for-stdostream-not-exactly-boostformat) attempt (quite a different level).

Comment: I see. A tuple is probably a better solution since I wouldn’t need the to_string_vector function at all then.

Comment: Well, [get](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) for the tuple gets the index as template-parameter, not as argument, so no, you would need something a bit different (either something like my data pack or array of wrappers... too complicated I guess, the vector is fine after all).

Comment: Right, didn't think of that. Maybe I should get some sleep :)
Btw, I like your approach. It does a lot more than I need in this particular case but definitely very interesting.

Answer (score 3):

As I already said in the comments, some white space would be good to add, especially around `{` and `}`. Then I mentioned that you could possibly avoid creating the vector of strings, but well, that's not that easy:

```
template<class... T> struct pack {
    static_assert(sizeof...(T) == 0, "Unmatched argument data");
    static constexpr size_t count = 0;

    template<class Action>
    bool exec(size_t pos, Action&& action = Action()) {
        return false;
    }
};
template<class T> struct pack<T> {
    static constexpr size_t count = 1;
    template<size_t I = 0> using type = std::enable_if_t<I == 0, T>;
    T value;
    pack() = default;
    template<class V>
    pack(V&& value) : value(std::forward<V>(value)) {}

    template<class Action>
    bool exec(size_t pos, Action&& action = Action()) {
        if (pos > 0) return false;
        action(value);
        return true;
    }
};
template<class T, class... Next> struct pack<T, Next...> {
    static constexpr size_t count = 1 + sizeof...(Next);
    template<size_t I = 0> using type = std::conditional_t<I == 0,
        T, typename pack<Next...>::template type<I == 0 ? 0 : I - 1>>;

    T value;
    pack<Next...> next;

    pack() = default;
    template<class First, class... Args>
    pack(First&& value, Args&&... args)
        : value(std::forward<First>(value))
        , next(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

    template<class Action>
    bool exec(size_t pos, Action&& action = Action()) {
        if (pos >= count) return false;
        if (pos == 0) action(value);
        else next.exec(pos - 1, std::forward<Action>(action));
        return true;
    }
};
template<class... Args>
inline auto make_pack(Args&&... args) {
    return pack<std::decay_t<Args>...>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
template<class... Args>
std::string format(std::string_view fmt, Args&& ...args) {
    auto pack = make_pack(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    std::ostringstream result;
    for (std::size_t at = 0; at < fmt.size();) {
        char c = fmt[at++];
        if (c == '{') {
            for (std::size_t start = at; at < fmt.size();) {
                c = fmt[at++];
                if (c == '}') {
                    try {
                        std::size_t index = std::stoi(std::string{ fmt.substr(start, at - 1 - start) });

                        if (index < pack.count)
                        {
                            pack.exec(index, [&result](auto it) { result << it; });
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (...) {
                    }
                    result << fmt.substr(start - 1, at - start + 1);
                    break;
                }
                if (c == '{') {
                    result << fmt.substr(start - 1, at - start + 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            result.put(c);
        }
    }
    return result.str();
}
```

I have also changed the indexing a bit, not that big of a difference.
The pack is in no way perfect (reduced version of my [`data pack`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/62765/variadic-template-data-pack-strucuture-designed-for-debug-trace-log-variable-si)) and `pack.exec(index, [&result](auto it) { result << it; });` is not easy for the compiler to optimize, but the machine code I have observed was not bad (two arguments, release build).

Answer (score 3):

`result.push_back((std::ostringstream{} << t).str());` does not compile with compilers that conform to the standard.

The `operator<<` actually returns a `basic_ostream&` which does not have a `str()` member. TT

---

We can use `std::array` instead of `std::vector`, and unpack the parameter pack directly into it:

```
template<class T>
std::string to_string(T&& t) {
    std::ostringstream sstr;
    sstr << t;
    return sstr.str();
}
...
auto values = std::array<std::string, sizeof...(Args)>{ to_string(std::forward<Args>(args))... };
```

---

Something to bear in mind: `std::stoi` is not very strict. It will parse something like `{ 1 267 hi there!}` as `1` without batting an eyelid.

Using `std::strtoul` or `std::strtoull` would allow the character after the last converted character to be checked (and also avoid creating a copy of the number substring).

In fact, we could use `std::strtoull` to do the parsing after finding the first `{`. If the last converted character is `}`, we have a valid index. Otherwise, the characters can just be copied over.

(This may be too fiddly to be worth any gains in efficiency though (especially when using `ostringstream` for conversions), but it's something to consider).

---

The parsed index is checked to be `< values.size()`, but it may also be negative. Consider using `result += values.at(index);` which will throw a `std::out_of_range` error and end up in your `catch` block.

Comment: I didn't notice the std::ostream thing since it works with clang, gcc and msvc without any warnings so thanks for pointing that out :)
I had a look at std::strtoul and it makes things significantly easier to write and read.
I completely ditched the inner loop and now just check if the character that was parsed last by std::strtoul is '}'.